# Administrators and Permissions

Tags: support, moderation, privileges

- Are there administrators?
- If so, who are they?
- If not, how will they be elected?
- Will the permissions and roles be updated?

---

##### UPDATES:

###### 15th March 2022 - [Leaving Private Beta & Initial Pro-Tem Moderator Election!](https://proofassistants.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/166/leaving-private-beta-initial-pro-tem-moderator-election)

Comment: This site will use the same moderation system as the rest of the StackExchange network, although as Glorfindel notes, there are some differences while the site is brand new.

Comment: I am a Stack CM, just popping in here to say hi. I won't be the only CM around during the site's beta, but I'm covering launch day, including moderation duties if they should appear (though, hopefully it's all just paperwork!)

Comment: @Slate ok. thanks. Great to know. Hope u have fun :)

Comment: @Slate Are you still with us? Can you give any information on how many more days we have left for the private beta to end? Thank You!

Comment: @HenryWHHackv3.0b I thought that private beta ends when we complete all the  goals on the [Area 51 Proposal site](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/126242/proof-assistants)

Comment: We generally give the site 4 weeks before evaluating whether or not it can leave private beta, @HenryWHHackv3.0b — that means y'all are up for revision next Tuesday, and should expect to hear from us at some point next week.

Comment: @JNat Great, thanks for the reply. Looking forward to hearing from you! :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Are there administrators?

Right now, [Community Managers (Stack Exchange employees)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/99338/295232) take care of administrative tasks.

> If not, how will they be elected?

If the proposal generates enough activity, a [Pro-Tempore election](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/314459/295232) will be held. Members with more than 300 reputation will be able to nominate themselves as ♦ moderators and members with more than 150 reputation will be able to vote on them.

Answer (score 6):

Glorfindel's post answers the first three questions, about administrators and elections, so I will answer the fourth and last question in your post, which is about permissions, since they differ during Private Beta compared to other sites in the network. The exact reputation levels you need in order to gain permissions to do certain things, are explained in a table here: [What are the reputation requirements for privileges on sites, and how do they differ per site?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/58587/391772).

Comment: Roughly 3 weeks. Maybe more.