# Leaving Private Beta & Initial Pro-Tem Moderator Election!

Tags: discussion, election, beta

Congratulations! You've met the participation and engagement expectations for an active private beta site and will be going into public beta tomorrow!

As we’re getting ready to wrap up the private beta for Proof Assistants Stack Exchange, that means it’s time to start thinking about what comes next: the election to choose your first pro-tem moderators.

### What does it take to be a Moderator?

Prior to 2018, [pro-tem moderators were picked by staff](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/moderator-pro-tempore/), and the Community Management team would look for users who:

- Have a reasonably high reputation score to indicate active, consistent participation.
- Show an interest in their meta’s community-building activities.
- Lead by example, showing patience and respect for their fellow community members in everything they write.
- Exhibit those intangible traits discussed in [A Theory of Moderation](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/05/a-theory-of-moderation/).
- Have an eye for content that should be flagged, closed or removed and act on that within the expectations of the community and Stack Exchange generally.

### Electing your moderators

In 2018, however, we started experimenting with hosting elections for beta sites to choose their pro-tem moderators, in addition to the community-elected moderators in sites not in Beta, in the rest of the network. The process is mostly the same, but if you’re interested in the full details, see [the announcement on Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/314459/experimenting-with-pro-tempore-elections).

In accordance with that, I’m here today to announce this site’s first pro-tem election and invite users interested in nominating to state their intention to do so here. Additionally, if you feel someone would be a good fit as a moderator on this site, feel free to use an answer to this question to support them and encourage them to run.

### The timeline:

- Starting on 21 March, users can nominate themselves on the [election page](https://proofassistants.stackexchange.com/election/1). Users can also ask questions on meta for potential moderators to answer. (Use the [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion) and [election](/questions/tagged/election) tags.)
- On 28 March, if there are 4 or more candidates, we'll run an election. If not, I'll extend the nomination period for a week. If, at the end of that extension period there are still less than 4 candidates, I'll simply appoint the candidates. (There's a small chance we'll need to [remove a nomination](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/274114/lets-disallow-nominations-from-people-whove-been-suspended-in-the-past-year), but I doubt that will come up.)
- If there is an election, I'll announce the results on meta on 5 April (or 12 April, if we need to extend the nomination period).

#### NOTE:

- **This is not an official election nomination thread.** It’s just a space to get some conversation about potential nominees going and a notion of who would be willing to step up, so you don't have to put up your whole election nomination here.

If you have any questions about the process, please stick them in an answer here.

Comment: 4 candidates *is* the usual for an election. You always need the number of seats (3) plus one (3+1=4) for an *election* to happen.

Comment: Congratulations guys! We got here! I just wanna say well done to all of you for playing your part in getting us here :) <3

Comment: Do we know if / when we will be added to the sites list [here](https://stackexchange.com/sites)?

Comment: @taylor.2317 That's part of being a public site. I'll let you know when the actual changeover happens.

Comment: @Catija ok great, thanks!

Comment: Who are eligible for nominating?

Comment: @taylor.2317 we show up now, see https://stackexchange.com/sites#newest

Comment: @Glorfindel Yay! Thanks for the message! <3

Comment: @ice1000 Nominating requires 300 reputation. 150 reputation is required to *vote*. Both of these are visible if you look at the election page linked in the question, on their respective tabs (nominations, election).